# Cannot write randomly generated int to DB from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have generated a random int between 100000 and 999999, and want to write it to my DB on the fly (code below). I am loading an existing record (client) and wish to write the `randomNumber` to the field Token for that existing record.

The `int` generates fine, as I can store in `ViewBag` and render in my view, but cannot write to DB for an unknown reason. No errors during build, and `Token` exists in my DB and Model.

I have also tried just using `Token = randomNumber.ToString();` with no success.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SendForm(int ? id)
{            
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Client clients = db.Clients.Find(id);
    if (clients == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    Random rndNumber = new Random();
    int randomNumber = rndNumber.Next(100000,999999);
    ViewBag.rndNumber = randomNumber.ToString();
    var client = new Client()
    {
       Token = ViewBag.rndNumber,
    };
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View(clients);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

newly created object must be added into `DbSet` in order `EF` to detect that new object has been created.

```
var client = new Client()
{
    Token = ViewBag.rndNumber,
};
db.Clients.Add(client);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If you want to **update** existing client

```
clients.Token = randomNumber
db.SaveChanges();
```

*Note `clients` in fact is single entity, since `Find` is same as `SingleOrDefault`, so just misleading name*

Comment: Thanks. I should have clarified - I am loading an existing record, and want to update the "Token" field at the same time. I will amend the question.

Comment: that's great, working perfectly now. thanks again. clearly was overthinking it...